# Can I print the console log of my discord bot into a specific channel in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a discord bot which will send a dm to a particular user if the staff types
"!ping<@mentionusername>"
so, i want my bot to record its console logs of node.js in a particular channel so that other staff members can also see the logs instead of just the developer. Can anyone share with me the code for it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create your own log function, or hooking the `console.log` function.

Simple way:

```
function log(msg) 
{
    console.log(msg);
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'log');
    if (!channel) return;
    channel.send(msg);
}
```